# Wordpress: Twig file not rendering changes in browser

Tags: wordpress, caching, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I think I'm having some kind of cache issue or maybe I'm so new to timber/twig that I'm completely missing something? I'm using developer tools and can see that the page is using the hero_jobs.php controller file which is what it's supposed to use, and the page hero is rendering the ACF for job image, but all of a sudden I'm making small changes to the twig file and none of the changes are rendering in the browser. I first just tried to change the class I have on the image which would have nothing to do with the controller file. Nothing changed in browser. I also deleted the code for the job image, image still rendering in browser. The site uses the componentizer plugin and the ACF field group for the Job Hero is pointing to the correct controller file.

I've disabled the cache in developer tools, I researched how to disable cache in timber, uninstalled WC3 cache and I also installed a clear timber cache plugin. Still not rendering my changes. I'm at a loss for what to try, or if the issue is a cache problem?

I think I'm also having a cache issue on the back end. I've updated the field group and deleted two fields and added two new ones, they were appearing in the editor, and now they've reverted back to the old fields. I

I'm running MAMP and I've tried restarting it, restarting my computer, restoring the database and site files from Time Machine, and still it's showing the wrong fields.

I've taken on creating a new template for my employer's website that was developed by a big outside company so it's quite complicated but I'm learning.

UPDATE: I found the timber.php file where the cache settings are, and set them all to CACHE_NONE but I'm still not getting the template to render.

````
        /**
 * Compile a Twig file.
 *
 * Passes data to a Twig file and returns the output.
 *
 * @api
 * @example
 * ```php
 * $data = array(
 *     'firstname' => 'Jane',
 *     'lastname' => 'Doe',
 *     'email' => 'jane.doe@example.org',
 * );
 *
 * $team_member = Timber::compile( 'team-member.twig', $data );
 * ```
 * @param array|string $filenames  Name of the Twig file to render. If this is an array of files, Timber will
 *                                 render the first file that exists.
 * @param array        $data       Optional. An array of data to use in Twig template.
 * @param bool|int     $expires    Optional. In seconds. Use false to disable cache altogether. When passed an
 *                                 array, the first value is used for non-logged in visitors, the second for users.
 *                                 Default false.
 * @param string       $cache_mode Optional. Any of the cache mode constants defined in TimberLoader.
 * @param bool         $via_render Optional. Whether to apply optional render or compile filters. Default false.
 * @return bool|string The returned output.
 */
public static function compile( $filenames, $data = array(), $expires = false, $cache_mode = Loader::CACHE_NONE, $via_render = false ) {
    if ( !defined('TIMBER_LOADED') ) {
        self::init();
    }
    $caller = LocationManager::get_calling_script_dir(1);
    $loader = new Loader($caller);
    $file = $loader->choose_template($filenames);

    $caller_file = LocationManager::get_calling_script_file(1);
    apply_filters('timber/calling_php_file', $caller_file);

    if ( $via_render ) {
        $file = apply_filters('timber_render_file', $file);
    } else {
        $file = apply_filters('timber_compile_file', $file);
    }

    $output = false;

    if ($file !== false) {
        if ( is_null($data) ) {
            $data = array();
        }

        if ( $via_render ) {
            $data = apply_filters('timber_render_data', $data);
        } else {
            $data = apply_filters('timber_compile_data', $data);
        }

        $output = $loader->render($file, $data, $expires, $cache_mode);
    }

    do_action('timber_compile_done');
    return $output;
}
````

Comment: Enable `auto_reload` for `twig`

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that since I'm new to this, the answers I'm getting when I try and research it is only giving me Drupal, and I'm using wordpress.

Comment: Not sure either. Don't have a WP running with timber/twig myself. `auto_reload` is an option you can pass to the constructor of twig.. Did you try using `TimberLoader::clear_cache_timber();`?

Comment: I found where to edit the timber cache in the plugin folder and set it all to CACHE_NONE but the twig file is still not rendering anything new.

Comment: Yes I tried TimberLoader::clear_cache_timber(); in the controller file yesterday, no such luck. I'm wondering if I'm having a MAMP issue or something strange happening, this morning I had to do a MAMP update because mysql kept crashing.

Comment: Wait just kidding, I tried something similar, but when I try that I get errors and it says it's depreciated.... hmmm

Comment: Take a look at how the `hero_jobs.php` file calls the `.twig` file through `Timber::render` — can you paste `hero_jobs.php` contents?

Comment: Simple one time fix: delete the `cache` directory in `plugins/timber-library`. You'd need to do this every time your twig files change.